# Pasar varios códigos a sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo un **store procedure** que hace una selección mediante un `where codcliente In(@paramer1,@parameter2)`.

El problema es que si quiero consultar Varios códigos contenidos en un `Gridview` solo le paso cuando esté seleccionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas IN no puedes pasar parametros en este caso si vas a tener que concatener en un string los valores

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.Add("valor1")
list.Add("valor2")

Using cnx As New SqlConnection("connection string")

    Dim query As String = "select * from <tabla> WHERE campo IN ('{0}')"
    query = String.Format(query, String.Join("','", list))

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cnx)

    Dim adaptador As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    adaptador.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Using
```

como veras usando un List(Of ) puede definir la lista de valores y los unes mediante el String.Join() separandolos por coma

Comment: Gracias leandro mira cual es mi caso tengo un datagridview con 3 campos condcliente,nombre,seleccionar (este ultimo un campo booleano) y si selecciono 8 código  tengo que hacer un select * from dbo.prestamos where codcliente in(aquí tengo que pasar el código seleccionado) ese es mi problema

Comment: @JOSEANGELRAMIREZHERNANDEZ si puedes obtener los id's de los elementos seleccionados en el `GridView`, el código que ofrece Leandro en su respuesta te sirve. Actualiza tu pregunta describiendo el problema completo que enfrentas en este momento.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias probaré ese ejemplo y les dejo saber

Answer (score 0):

En alguna ocasión yo lo hice mediante una función tipo tabla en `SQL Server`, es decir, en el procedimiento recibía un `string` con todos los códigos a procesar separados por un delimitador, y posteriormente pasaba ese `string` a la funcion, lo cual me lo devolvia en una tabla, ya que tenia esa tabla con cada codigo podia insertarlos en una tabla temporal para hacer `JOIN's`, `WHERE ... IN ()`, o lo que requiera.

el codigo de la funcion para dividir la cadena desde `SQL Server` es el siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [SplitWords](@text varchar(MAX),@delims varchar(10) = '|')
RETURNS @words TABLE (
pos smallint,
value varchar(8000)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET @text = RTRIM(@text)

DECLARE @pos smallint, @i smallint, @s varchar(8000)

SET @pos = 1

WHILE @pos < LEN(@text)
AND CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, 1), @delims) > 0
SET @pos = @pos + 1

WHILE @pos <= LEN(@text)
BEGIN
SET @i = PATINDEX('%[' + @delims + ']%',
SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, len(@text) - @pos + 1))
IF @i > 0
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + @pos - 1
IF @i > @pos
BEGIN
-- @i now holds the earliest delimiter in the string
SET @s = SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, @i - @pos)
INSERT INTO @words
VALUES (@pos, @s)
END
SET @pos = @i + 1

WHILE @pos < LEN(@text)
AND CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, 1), @delims) > 0
SET @pos = @pos + 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @s = SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, LEN(@text) - @pos + 1)
INSERT INTO @words
VALUES (@pos, @s) SET @pos = LEN(@text) + 1
END
END
--Remove spaces
UPDATE @words
SET value=LTRIM(RTRIM(value))
-- remove common words that we don't want to search for
DELETE FROM @words
WHERE --value IN ('de', 'y', 'o', 'a', '&')
    LEN(value)=0
RETURN
END
```

El primer parámetro es la cadena de texto a dividir, y el segundo parámetro define el delimitador, por default es el caracter '|'. Y la función devuelve una variable tipo tabla indicando la posición en que se encontró un delimitador y el valor que esta posterior a él, al final yo le modifique para que eliminara las filas que no tuvieran contenido en la columna value `LEN(value)=0`, eso debes evaluar si lo requieres de igual forma.